# Using Color Picker Dialog with fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to update an app to use the material design menu drawer. Using [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/) I have the app pretty much working, each of the fragments loads and shows the right screen information. The problem is part of the app is a color picker dialog. I cannot seem to find the page I found this dialog at anymore. It works fine when ran from the main activity like I'm currently doing it in two apps. 
Here is the color picker I'm using:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class ColorPicker extends Dialog {

    public interface OnColorChangedListener {
        void colorChanged(int color);
    }

    private OnColorChangedListener mListener;
    private int mInitialColor;

    private static class ColorPickerView extends View {
        private Paint mPaint;
        private Paint mCenterPaint;
        private final int[] mColors;
        private OnColorChangedListener mListener;

        ColorPickerView(Context c, OnColorChangedListener l, int color) {
            super(c);
            mListener = l;
            mColors = new int[] {
                    0xFFFF0000, 0xFFFF00FF, 0xFF0000FF, 0xFF00FFFF, 0xFF00FF00,
                    0xFFFFFF00, 0xFFFF0000
            };
            Shader s = new SweepGradient(0, 0, mColors, null);

            mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            mPaint.setShader(s);
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            //sets the size of the outer ring
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(60);
            //mPaint.setStrokeWidth(32); original value

            mCenterPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            mCenterPaint.setColor(color);
            mCenterPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        }

        private boolean mTrackingCenter;
        private boolean mHighlightCenter;

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            float r = CENTER_X - mPaint.getStrokeWidth()*0.5f;

            canvas.translate(CENTER_X, CENTER_X);

            canvas.drawOval(new RectF(-r, -r, r, r), mPaint);
            canvas.drawCircle(0, 0, CENTER_RADIUS, mCenterPaint);

            if (mTrackingCenter) {
                int c = mCenterPaint.getColor();
                mCenterPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

                if (mHighlightCenter) {
                    mCenterPaint.setAlpha(0xFF);
                } else {
                    mCenterPaint.setAlpha(0x80);
                }
                canvas.drawCircle(0, 0, CENTER_RADIUS + mCenterPaint.getStrokeWidth(), mCenterPaint);

                mCenterPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
                mCenterPaint.setColor(c);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            setMeasuredDimension(CENTER_X*2, CENTER_Y*2);
        }
        //changes the size of the color picker
        private static final int CENTER_X = 300;
        private static final int CENTER_Y = 300;
        private static final int CENTER_RADIUS = 200;

        private int ave(int s, int d, float p) {
            return s + java.lang.Math.round(p * (d - s));
        }

        private int interpColor(int colors[], float unit) {
            if (unit <= 0) {
                return colors[0];
            }
            if (unit >= 1) {
                return colors[colors.length - 1];
            }

            float p = unit * (colors.length - 1);
            int i = (int)p;
            p -= i;

            int c0 = colors[i];
            int c1 = colors[i+1];
            int a = ave(Color.alpha(c0), Color.alpha(c1), p);
            int r = ave(Color.red(c0), Color.red(c1), p);
            int g = ave(Color.green(c0), Color.green(c1), p);
            int b = ave(Color.blue(c0), Color.blue(c1), p);

            return Color.argb(a, r, g, b);
        }

        private static final float PI = 3.1415926f;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            float x = event.getX() - CENTER_X;
            float y = event.getY() - CENTER_Y;
            boolean inCenter = java.lang.Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y) <= CENTER_RADIUS;

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    mTrackingCenter = inCenter;
                    if (inCenter) {
                        mHighlightCenter = true;
                        invalidate();
                        break;
                    }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (mTrackingCenter) {
                        if (mHighlightCenter != inCenter) {
                            mHighlightCenter = inCenter;
                            invalidate();
                        }
                    } else {
                        float angle = (float)java.lang.Math.atan2(y, x);
                        float unit = angle/(2*PI);
                        if (unit < 0) {
                            unit += 1;
                        }
                        mCenterPaint.setColor(interpColor(mColors, unit));
                        invalidate();
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if (mTrackingCenter) {
                        if (inCenter) {
                            mListener.colorChanged(mCenterPaint.getColor());
                        }
                        mTrackingCenter = false;
                        invalidate();
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

this is the error I keep seeing:

```
Process: com.comsofinteractive.tipcalculator, PID: 29536
    android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:743)
            at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:298)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:87)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:313)
            at com.comsofinteractive.tipcalculator.activity.MessagesFragment.onClick(MessagesFragment.java:110)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5254)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21179)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6843)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Here are lines 109 and 110, 110 is where the problem is according to the above log- assuming I read it right. These are in an onclick event.

```
ColorPicker font = new ColorPicker( getActivity().getApplication(), this, Color.WHITE);
font.show();
```

I have read through a few posts about using fragments and dialogs, some from here some from other forums, none of the answers given seem to solve my problem. Any help with being pointed in the direction of an answer would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ApplicationContext` should not be used for tasks such as creating Dialogs. As you are in a fragment you can instead get the Activity-Context simply by calling the Fragments `getActivity()` method.

Actually, I was getting the same issue.

**Replace following line:**

```
ColorPicker font = new ColorPicker( getActivity().getApplication(), this, Color.WHITE);
```

**With**

```
ColorPicker font = new ColorPicker( getActivity(), this, Color.WHITE);
```

Comment: @ComSof-I Welcome.